# Redirect to list view after saving the opportunity in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, list

I have one requirement where i need to redirect to list view after saving the opportunity record. Is here anyway we can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to List view by specifying listviewId in force:navigateToList.
Please see the example below.

```
gotoList : function (component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getListViews");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var listviews = response.getReturnValue();
            var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToList");
            navEvent.setParams({
                "listViewId": listviews.Id,
                "listViewName": null,
                "scope": "Opportunity"
            });
            navEvent.fire();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<ListView> getListViews() {
    List<ListView> listviews = 
        [SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType = 'Opportunity'];

    // Perform isAccessible() check here
    return listviews;
}
```

For more details click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToList.htm)